# How to get list in jsp

Tags: java, html, list, jsp

AI have this code:
fileOne.java:
...

```
em.persist(new Item("A1","B1","C1","A.jpg","abc"));
em.persist(new Item("A2","B2","C2","B.jpg","abc"));
em.persist(new Item("A3","B3","C3","C.jpg","abc"));
```

...

fileTwo.jsp:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<Item> myList = (List<Item>)request.getAttribute("Item");

            %>
    <span style="font-size: 150%; color: black; text-decoration: underline;">List:</span>
    <table id="Table" style="display:block;">
        <tr>
             <th>A</th>
             <th>B</th>
             <th>C</th>
        </tr>
        <% if(myList != null){
            int counter = 0;
            for (Item Citem: myList ) { %>
               <tr> 
                <td id="viewA<%=counter%>" ><%= Citem.getA()%></td>
                <td id="viewB<%=counter%>" ><%= Citem.getB()%></td>
                <td id="viewC<%=counter%>" ><%= Citem.getC()%></td>
                <td id="viewImage<%=counter%>"><img alt="itemimg" src="ItemsImage<%= Citem.getImageUrl() %>" width="52" height="52"></td>
              </tr>
              <% counter++;
                    }
                }
            else{
                %>  Empty; 
                <%}
              %>

    </table>
```

...

And I want to view the `List<Item>` in a table on my HTML page.
and I get only "Empty" in the page (and the header "List").

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `em.persist()`. What is `em` as it is not a `List` (`List` does not have a `persist()` method).

Comment: So what do you offer?

Comment: If you get "Empty", that means that request.getAttribute("Item") returns null. So check that you have indeed stored a list of items under the request attribute "Item" before executing the JSP. And please stop using scriptlets. Learn the JSP EL and the JSTL.

Comment: @yoka, I am asking that you make your question clearer. We don't understand what `em` means (what type is it and how are the list stored in the "`request`"). Please provide your code that can make this problem clearer for us to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try it

JAVA code

```
List<Map> em = null;

em.add( new HashMap<String, String>(){{
            put("A","A1");
            put("B","B1");
            put("C","C1");
            put("url","url1 here");
            put("msg","message1 here");
        }});

em.add( new HashMap<String, String>(){{
            put("A","A2");
            put("B","B2");
            put("C","C2");
            put("url","url2 here");
            put("msg","message2 here");
        }});
em.add( new HashMap<String, String>(){{
            put("A","A3");
            put("B","B3");
            put("C","C3");
            put("url","url3 here");
            put("msg","message3 here");
        }});
```

jsp code

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${Item}" var="subItem" varStatus="theCount">
         <tr> 
             <td id="viewA<c:out value="${theCount.count}" />" ><c:out value="${subItem.A}" /></td>
             <td id="viewB<c:out value="${theCount.count}" />" ><c:out value="${subItem.B}" /></td>
             <td id="viewC<c:out value="${theCount.count}" />" ><c:out value="${subItem.C}" /></td>
             <td id="viewImage<c:out value="${theCount.count}" />"><img alt="itemimg" src="<c:out value="${subItem.url}" />" width="52" height="52"></td>
         </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

try it even you don't need to check for null if its null then it returns blanck table not throw any exception.

and add following taglib in jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the entity manager, you will have to write a finder method that returns a list. For an ex

```
Query query = em.createQuery("FROM Item item WHERE item.name = ?");
query.setParameter(1, "abc");
List<Item> items = query.getResultList();
```

and set the items to the request.

```
request.setAttribute("Items", items);
```

em.persist will just persist the object.